# file handling-the error: no match for 'operator>>' in while loop (c++)(code::block)

Tags: c++

I wrote the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ofstream theFile("students_info.txt");
  cout<<"Enter the data as requested"<<endl;
  cout<<"Press ctrl+z to exit"<<endl;

  string name, address;
  int contact[10];

  while(cin >> name >> address >> contact) {
    theFile << "\nName: "     << name
            << "\n Address: " << address
            << "\nContact: "  << contact[10] << endl;
  }

  theFile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

I get the following compile error from my while loop condition:

> no match for 'operator>>'

From what i understood, my condition means if not in this order of entry of cin, leave the loop!!

edited:solved my problem
1:There is no operator>> for an array.
2:could simply use int type
3:if had to use array ..need to put it one by one..

thank you for helping me

Comment: `int contact[10];` if you want 10 integers you need to read them one by one. There is no operator>> for an array.

Comment: oh!!! yes it seems to work perfectly now.. but i want int type for my contact ...how may i do that??

Comment: sorryjust int type is fine...how can i be this stupid!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost alright. This would have been ok:

```
while(cin >> name >> address) {
    ..
}
```

But, the `operator >>` cannot handle an array of ints (`int contact[10]`)! So you have to read it int by int, for example:

```
while(cin >> name >> address >> contact[0] >> contact[1] >> ...) {
    ..
}
```

or replace this with:

```
while(true) {
    cin >> name;
    if (!isValidName(name))
        return; // or handle otherwise

    cin >> address;
    if (!isValidAddress(address))
        return; // or handle otherwise

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(contact)/sizeof(contact[0]); i++) {
        cin >> contact[i];
        if (!isValidContact(contact[i])
            return; // or handle otherwise
    }     
}
```

Notice that I added input validation. Always validate user input!

Comment: `contact[0] << contact[1] <<` you meant `>>`